# How do you use tar to unzip a file in a dockerfile when using FROM perl

Tags: perl, dockerfile, tar

I'm trying to make a Docker container for a `perl` script, `CooVar`, but seem to be running into issues because the `tar` command is not available.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM perl:5.20


RUN mkdir /tmp/install
WORKDIR /tmp/install

# Install cpan modules
RUN cpanm install Cwd Getopt::Long POSIX File::Basename List::Util Bio::DB::Fasta Bio::Seq Bio::SeqUtils Bio::SeqIO Set::IntervalTree Set::IntSpan

# Download CooVar-v0.07
RUN wget -O /usr/local/bin/CooVar-0.07.tar.gz http://genome.sfu.ca/projects/coovar/CooVar-0.07.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf /usr/local/bin/CooVar-0.07.tar.gz

# Set WORKDIR to /data -- predefined mount location.
RUN mkdir /data
WORKDIR /data

# And clean up
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/install

# Set Entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["perl", "/usr/local/bin/coovar-0.07/coovar.pl"]
```

> *Note:* I think the use of an `Entrypoint` here is preventing me from exploring a `Docker` containers file system via `docker exec -t -i mycontainer /bin/bash` but that's not a big issue as  i think I know the problem from the error below.

### Error

When I run this from `Snakemake` I was including `ls /usr/bin so I can see what was in the container (very new to` Docker`and not sure the best way to develop/debug yet). You can see that the`.tar.gz`was not unzipped so it looks like`tar` is not working in this case.

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root   2137 Oct 10 12:36 .
drwxrwxr-x 10 root root    147 May  5  2016 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 176772 Nov 20  2012 CooVar-0.07.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 112680 May  5  2016 a2p
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2861 Oct 10 12:35 bp_aacomp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3696 Oct 10 12:35 bp_bioflat_index
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1605 Oct 10 12:35 bp_biogetseq
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2803 Oct 10 12:35 bp_dbsplit
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2866 Oct 10 12:35 bp_extract_feature_seq
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4002 Oct 10 12:35 bp_fastam9_to_table
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   7385 Oct 10 12:35 bp_fetch
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1809 Oct 10 12:35 bp_filter_search
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  15121 Oct 10 12:35 bp_find-blast-matches
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3427 Oct 10 12:35 bp_gccalc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  79742 Oct 10 12:35 bp_genbank2gff3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4617 Oct 10 12:35 bp_index
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1877 Oct 10 12:35 bp_local_taxonomydb_query
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3239 Oct 10 12:35 bp_make_mrna_protein
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4898 Oct 10 12:35 bp_mask_by_search
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3041 Oct 10 12:35 bp_mrtrans
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4292 Oct 10 12:35 bp_mutate
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    927 Oct 10 12:35 bp_nexus2nh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3533 Oct 10 12:35 bp_nrdb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   6331 Oct 10 12:35 bp_oligo_count
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   7317 Oct 10 12:35 bp_process_gadfly
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3752 Oct 10 12:35 bp_process_sgd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  24416 Oct 10 12:35 bp_revtrans-motif
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4190 Oct 10 12:35 bp_search2alnblocks
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  12519 Oct 10 12:35 bp_search2gff
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2455 Oct 10 12:35 bp_search2table
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2739 Oct 10 12:35 bp_search2tribe
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1779 Oct 10 12:35 bp_seq_length
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2289 Oct 10 12:35 bp_seqconvert
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3833 Oct 10 12:35 bp_seqcut
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4595 Oct 10 12:35 bp_seqpart
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2339 Oct 10 12:35 bp_seqret
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1549 Oct 10 12:35 bp_seqretsplit
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4291 Oct 10 12:35 bp_split_seq
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   5912 Oct 10 12:35 bp_sreformat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3243 Oct 10 12:35 bp_taxid4species
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2940 Oct 10 12:35 bp_taxonomy2tree
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1624 Oct 10 12:35 bp_translate_seq
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1488 Oct 10 12:35 bp_tree2pag
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   7504 Oct 10 12:35 bp_unflatten_seq
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root  36619 May  5  2016 c2ph
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   7144 Oct 10 12:33 config_data
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  12804 May  5  2016 corelist
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   5873 May  5  2016 cpan
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 303998 May  5  2016 cpanm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  41760 Oct 10 12:24 enc2xs
```

Anyone know how I can fix this `Dockerfile`?

Comment: You ran the `tar xvf` in `/tmp/install` and then nuked that directory afterwards. Unpacked files will not magically show up in /usr/bin then. And you can, in fact, [override the entry point](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime)

Comment: It looks like you utilize `apt-get clean`, then why do not do `apt-get install tar` -- unpack tar file and after `apt-get remove tar`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on override [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) - that speeds up troubleshooting for me.
Probably I should just use `WORKDIR /usr/local/bin` in this case as I want the `coovar` directory there.

Comment: [Polar Bear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12313309/polar-bear) I tried your suggestion of `RUN apt-get remove tar` after but I get an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: gnupg but it is not going to be installed
 libuuid1 : Depends: passwd but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: uuid-runtime but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get remove tar' returned a non-zero code: 100
```